# How to paste richtext into MS Word "form" using using SelectContentControlsByTag and formattedText

Tags: c#, forms, ms-word, rtf

in ms word 
I'm trying to copy the richtext string that I've saved in the database
but looks like I can't set the formattedText directly as gives an error :

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range'

code cut:

```
var rtf = tq.Descr_Rtf;//dr["tq_descr_rtf"] + "";
            if (rtf != "")
            {
                try { System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(rtf, System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Rtf); }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }


                wd.SelectContentControlsByTag("Descr")[1].Range.FormattedText = rtf;
            }
            else
            {
                wd.SelectContentControlsByTag("Descr")[1].Range.FormattedText.Text = tq.Descr;// rtf;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FormattedText` property only works between two `Ranges` in open Word document(s).

RTF is not a "native" format, as far as Word is concerned. You can't write RTF coding to Word using the object model and have Word format come out - all you get is a string of characters (the RTF encoding).

Word's native format is Word Open XML, and that must be inserted (in the OPC flat file version) using the `InsertXML` method.

The only ways you can bring RTF into Word and have it converted to Word format are

1. saving the RTF to a file and using the `InsertFile` method OR
2. put the RTF on the clipboard and then paste it into Word. OR
3. you have to write (or find) a converstion library that converts RTF to valid Word Open XML (in the OPC flat file format).